# R: aggregating values between two time periods

Tags: r, time, between

I have a dataframe with trades, along with the open times of these trades. I'm trying to find the equity at the time of the trade. However, I only have equity at the beginning of each hour, so I'm adding any deposits/withdrawals between the start of the hour and the time of the trade to this equity.

I have a method for doing so with a for loop, indicated below:

```
 for (i in 1:nrow(tradeData))
        {  
           tradeData$EquityUSD [i] = hourlyData$EquityUSD[which(as.character(hourlyData$Period) ==
             min(hourlyData$Period[as.character(hourlyData$Period) >= as.character(tradeData$OpenTime [i])]))-1] #Find equity as of start of the hour
          tradeData$EquityUSD [i] = tradeData$EquityUSD [i] + sum(tradeData$ProfitUSD[tradeData$CloseTime <= tradeData$OpenTime[i] &
              tradeData$CloseTime >= tradeHour$TradeHour[i]]) #Add any profit realised from closed trades before current trade, but in current hour only
          tradeData$EquityUSD [i] = tradeData$EquityUSD [i] + sum(currentNetDep$DepositWithdrawal[currentNetDep$Time <= tradeData$OpenTime [i] &currentNetDep$Time >= tradeHour$TradeHour[i]])      #Add any deposits/withdrawals from closed trades before current trade, but in current hour only
        }
```

The hourlyData dataframe just contains equity at the beginning of every hour, on the hour.

This works, placing the equity at the time of the trade into the tradeData table. However, it is incredibly slow, especially if the client has a lot of trades in the time period.

Here is a sample of the hourlyData dataframe:

```
Login   NetExposure EquityUSD        Period           
173929  108791.2    1000         2014-01-16 18:00:00.000
173929  108792.0    1200         2014-01-16 19:00:00.000
173929  108737.6    1500         2014-01-16 20:00:00.000
173929  108794.4    1300         2014-01-16 21:00:00.000
173929  108913.6    1400         2014-01-16 22:00:00.000
173929  108947.2    1600         2014-01-16 23:00:00.000
```

And a sample of the deposit data:

```
 Login    DepositTime             DepositAmount
 173929   2014-01-16 19:30:00      100
 173929   2014-01-16 19:50:00      -200
```

And a sample of the tradeData dataframe:

```
Login        OpenTime            CloseTime              Equity 
173929      2014-01-16 18:30:00  2014-01-16 33:00:00     1000
173929      2014-01-16 18:35:00  2014-01-16 18:40:00     1000     
173929      2014-01-16 19:38:00  2014-01-16 22:32:00     1200 + 100 deposit    
173929      2014-01-16 19:40:00  2014-01-16 19:50:00     1200 + 100 deposit     
173929      2014-01-16 19:51:30  2014-01-16 19:59:40     1200 + 100 - 200 deposit
```

The first trade has equity equal to equity at the beginning of the hour.
The same is true of the second trade
The third trade has equity equal to equity at the beginning of the hour + deposit made in the same hour, but before the trade.
The same is true of the fourth trade, which contains two deposits post the beginning of the hour, but prior to the current trade

Please not that I've adjusted the answer to no longer require the Profit calculation

Does anyone know of a more efficient manner in which to do this?
Also, please let me know if anything is unclear in the above.

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: Would it be a good approximation to linearly interpolate between equity? For example, equity for a closing trade at `2014-01-01 00:30:00` could just be (110+100)/2 = 105.

Comment: @TommyO'Dell, no, unfortunately not. That was my first suggestion as well, but apparently interpolation is not good enough, as there can be drastic fluctuations in equity during a period if the client is highly leveraged. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: No worries. Is your sample of `tradeData` missing a column for `EquityUSD`?

Comment: Well, yes. I guess the `EquityUSD` column in `tradeData`, prior to running the above mentioned for loop, would just contain all zeroes.

Comment: @Mike I think there is a much faster way with merges, sums, and differences. Can you provide example data, please?

Comment: @RichardHerron I've updated the question with an example. Please let me know if its sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `ave` and `cumsum` to sum the deposits within each hour, then add these back to the equity at the beginning of the hour.

I think this does what you want.

```
# hourly data
hourlyData <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Login   NetExposure EquityUSD        Period           
173929  108791.2    1000         '2014-01-16 18:00:00.000'
173929  108792.0    1200         '2014-01-16 19:00:00.000'
173929  108737.6    1500         '2014-01-16 20:00:00.000'
173929  108794.4    1300         '2014-01-16 21:00:00.000'
173929  108913.6    1400         '2014-01-16 22:00:00.000'
173929  108947.2    1600         '2014-01-16 23:00:00.000'    
                         ")
hourlyData$Period <- strptime(hourlyData$Period, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")

# trade data
tradeData <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Login        OpenTime            CloseTime              
173929      '2014-01-16 18:30:00'  '2014-01-16 18:33:00'
173929      '2014-01-16 18:35:00'  '2014-01-16 18:40:00'
173929      '2014-01-16 19:38:00'  '2014-01-16 22:32:00'
173929      '2014-01-16 19:40:00'  '2014-01-16 19:50:00'
173929      '2014-01-16 19:51:30'  '2014-01-16 19:59:40'
                         ")
tradeData$OpenTime <- strptime(tradeData$OpenTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
tradeData$CloseTime <- strptime(tradeData$CloseTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")

# deposit data
depositData <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Login DepositTime DepositAmount 
173929 '2014-01-16 19:30:00' 100 
173929 '2014-01-16 19:50:00' -200
                         ")
depositData$DepositTime <- strptime(depositData$DepositTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")

# merge
merged <- merge(x=hourlyData, y=depositData, 
                by.x=c("Login", "Period"), by.y=c("Login", "DepositTime"),
                all=TRUE)

# running sum of deposits within each hour
merged$Running <- ave(merged$DepositAmount,
                      merged$Login, format(merged$Period, "%Y-%m-%d %H"),
                      FUN=function(x) {
                          xx <- ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)
                          cumsum(xx)
                      })

# carry-forward top-of-the-hour equity
merged$EquityUSD1 <- ave(merged$EquityUSD,
                      merged$Login, format(merged$Period, "%Y-%m-%d %H"),
                      FUN=function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), x[1], x))

# add back running sum
merged$EquityUSD1 <- merged$EquityUSD1 + merged$Running
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not quite sure I understand though. I'm looking to merged the equity data into the tradeData dataframe, such that I have equity at all the dates in the tradeData dataframe (i.e. `2014-01-16 18:30:00, 2014-01-16 18:30:00` etc.). If I substitute `tradeData` for `hourlyData` in the above code, I run into trouble at the `MergedEquityUSD1` line, as the equity data is contained in the hourlyData dataframe, not the tradeData dataframe. Any suggestions? Thanks again for the reply!

Comment: Never mind, I was being a chop. I just merged the equity data into the tradeData and then replaced hourlyData with tradeData in all later calcs and it works. Thanks so much Richard!

Comment: hi. How would I alter the above code to include a column that sums all `netExposureUSD` when the `OpenTime` of a trade is greater than the `CloseTime` of another trade, but both occur in the same hour? For example, one closes at `13:34:00`, and another opens at `13:38:00`, I would like to add the `NetExposureUSD` of the closed trade to that of the newly opened trade. Any ideas? Thanks!